# Uniform convergence preserves continuity - limit interchange argument

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, continuity, uniform-convergence

> Let $D\subset R$ and for each $n\in N, fn : D \to R$ is continuous on
>   $D$. If the sequence $(fn)$ be uniformly convergent on D to a function
>   $f$, then $f$ is continuous on $D$

[From my post here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3424160/if-f-n-converges-uniformly-to-f-then-prove-that-lim-x-to-c-lim-n-to) I am allowed to interchange limits

If $c\in D$, 
then $$\lim_{x\to c} f(x) = \lim_{x\to c} \lim_{n\to \infty} f_n(x) =   \lim_{n\to \infty} \lim_{x\to c} f_n(x) =  \lim_{n\to \infty}f_n(c) = f(c)$$

so this proves $f$ is continuous on $D$?

Is this correct?
I have posted this method because I found it relatively simpler.