# Proof Verification: Show that $ f_n(x_n) \to f(c) \; $ forall $ \;x_n\to c$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification, uniform-convergence

> Let $(f_n)$ be a sequence of continuous functions such that $f_n\to f$
>   uniformly on $X.$ Show that $ f_n(x_n) \to f(c) \; $ for all sequences $ \;x_n\to
> c.$

I know that $f_n \to f$ uniformly where $f_n$ are continuous $\rightarrow f$ continuous

I [also know](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3424160/if-f-n-converges-uniformly-to-f-then-prove-that-lim-x-to-c-lim-n-to) that $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\lim_{x\to c} f_n(x)= \lim_{x\to c} \lim_{n\to \infty} f_n(x).$$

So can I prove it like this:

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} f_n(x_n)  =  \lim_{n\to \infty} \lim_{x\to c} f_n(x) =\lim_{x\to c} \lim_{n\to \infty} f_n(x) = \lim_{x\to c} f(x) = f(c)?$$

Comment: You link to a question: are you allowed to use that question and answer in your proof? If not, I would recommend an $\varepsilon/3$ style of argument.

Comment: @AdrianKeister that post is mine only, I have proved it rigorously. I want to know if I can apply it to prove this

Comment: Then I would say yes!

Comment: @AdrianKeister thanks, great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A standard $\varepsilon/3$-style argument works here (only we need $\varepsilon/2$ in this case). Let $\varepsilon>0.$ Because $f_n\to f$ uniformly on $X,$ there exists $N>0$ such that for every $n\ge N$ and $x\in X$ we have
$$|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}. $$
Similarly, because $f$ is continuous (the limit of continuous functions is continuous if the convergence is uniform), there exists $\tilde{N}>0$ such that for every $n\ge \tilde{N},$ we have $|f(x_n)-f(c)|<\dfrac{\varepsilon}{2}.$ Let $N'=\max(N,\tilde{N}),$ and assume $n\ge N'.$ Then
\begin{align*}
|f_n(x_n)-f(c)|&= |f_n(x_n)-f(x_n)+f(x_n)-f(c)|\\
&\le |f_n(x_n)-f(x_n)|+|f(x_n)-f(c)|\\
&<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}+\frac{\varepsilon}{2}\\
&=\varepsilon,
\end{align*} 
and we are done.